# Proof that MGF of log-normal distribution is finite

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, indefinite-integrals, moment-generating-functions

I'm trying to prove that $E[e^{tX}]$ finite, given that $X = e^Z$ and that $Z \sim N(0,1)$ for any value of t. I'm thinking about two approaches:

- One approach is to use the integral definition of Expectation but I'm struggling to derive the integral since I don't know how to handle the pdf part.

can I say that $F_x(X) = F_z(ln(x))/x$ and then use $F_z(ln(x))$ instead ?

- Another approach is to use taylor's expansion and use dominated convergence theorem but I'm also struggling to find the dominating function of the series.

Could someone please help me, if one of the approaches is correct ? and how to proceed in it.

Comment: the title and body of the question don't match. You're trying to compute the MGF of $X$ where $X=e^Z$ for $Z$ standard normal. In other words you're trying to compute the MGF of a [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), is that right ? If so, please edit accordingly.

Comment: Yes you are right, I changed the title, thanks for clarification!

Comment: The MGF of a log-normal does not converge for $t>0$, so would be difficult to prove it is finite, even though all the moments are finite

Comment: @Henry it doesn't even converge if it's a standard gaussian i.e. mean =0 and std = 1 ?

Comment: $$E[e^{tX}] = E[e^{te^Z}] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{te^z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{te^z -z^2/2}$$ which diverges for $t > 0$

Comment: ultimate_beaver: it is well known that the MGF of any lognormal does not converge and @ayeayemaung's expression demonstrates this  when it logarithm is a standard normal.  The more general expression $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{te^x -(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}\, dx$ does not converge for any $t>0$ and any $\mu$ and any $\sigma^2>0$